# Conceptual understanding of xlDown

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

We find last row using code line

```
  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

I am refreshing my conceptual understanding of xlDown. I refer to data in column B in Sheet1 as appended below.

[image: xldown_issue1]

My understaqnding of End(xlDown) has been that it searches from the top down finding the last used cell before a blank cell.Its concept can be simulated by pressing ctrl down. If we highlight a column that contains data intermixed with blanks and then press ctrl down - it will go to the cell before the first blank cell. Pressing ctrl down in Column B Sheet 1 takes to B2 and then to B18. But if I use the following code snippet I get the last row as 1048576.

[image: xldown_issue2]

What logic this code snippet follows?
Can  anyone explain it please to clarify this trivial issue.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, It clarifies it.

Comment: Note that .End only works with visible cells so may give the "wrong" answer when rows are hidden.

Comment: @Charles Williams Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the same result if you remove `.End()`:

```
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").Row
```

This is because `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B")` is already the last possible cell of the `B` column. Calling `.End()` on it is allowed, but does nothing because there is nowhere to go.

Otherwise your understanding is correct.